# POST data to API from mobile localhost

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, strapi

I have created a Reactjs application using `strapi`. When I used POST on the laptop it is successfully passing the data. When connected the localhost in  mobile and trying to pass the data it is showing me `Unhandled Runtime error`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile doesn't know what your desktop/laptop's `localhost` is.
If your mobile is on the same network (same WiFi) as your laptop, then you can use your laptop's public IP assigned by the router, instead of `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

To find your laptop IP, you can use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` depending on whether you use Linux/Unix or Windows.

Here's an example of how to look for your IP on linux:

```sh
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1
```

The response would look something like this:

```
inet 192.168.29.195 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.29.255
```

Where `192.168.29.195` is your laptop IP. On your mobile device, you can use it like `192.168.29.195:3000`.

Comment: I have connected my localhost to my mobile and I have followed every step you suggested. I am getting error after following these steps